# How to make a JavaScript cookie available to an entire ASP.NET web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies

I am making an ASP.NET web application and I have created a cookie in JavaScript using

```
document.cookie = "products=" + productId;
```

The cookie works fine in JS
However, in my ASP.NET controller, I try:

```
if (Request.Cookies["products"] != null)
    {
        // This code never runs
    }
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: If you go to `Application` -> `Cookies` in Chrome dev tools, do you see your cookie?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes its there, named "products"

Comment: Does the `Domain` value match up with your domain?

Comment: Oh, on further inspection, The cookie does not exist once the checkout page is loaded, which is on a separate controller. In fact the cookie only exists when pages are loaded by my "ProductsController". The cookie does not exist when a page is loaded by any other controller.

Comment: Ah sorted, I needed to add a path "document.cookie = "products=" + productId + "; path=/";" Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Ian You should add that as an answer to your own question so that we can upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I needed to add a "path" for the cookie to be available across the whole website (e.g. available on all controllers)

```
document.cookie = "products=" + productId + "; path=/";
```